# What Greek preposition is in “exorcism”, “ek” or “ex”?

Tags: etymology, prepositions, greek

I realize this may not be typical for this forum, but I have seen the term translated to English in another post.

I find exorcism explained with "ek" with the verb "horkizo”

> The word “Exorcism" is derived from the Greek preposition "ek" with the verb "horkizo" which means "I cause [someone] to swear" and refers to "putting the spirit or demon on oath, "or invoking a higher authority to bind the entity in order to control it and command it to act contrary to its own will." — [Sydney Library](https://www.library.sydney.edu.au/collections/rare-books/online-exhibitions/witchcraft/exorcism/exorcism.html)

But elwhere I often see the term explained by “Ex”+ “horkizo”, “ex” meaning “out of “.

Are these just two types of spelling for the same preposition?

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eks-) has << Danish  Prefix eks-

ex-, former
>>. But checking in English dictionaries shows that only the ex-form is reckoned to have entered the language. Of course, Ancient Greek originals would have had ἐξ-.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has reasonably been interpreted as a question about Greek.

Comment: I'm voting to "leave open" because there might be an interesting question here about etymology...

Answer (score 2):

This prefix is the Ancient Greek [ἐξ (ex-)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%90%CE%BE#Ancient_Greek) which appears in many other Latin and English words.

[ἐκ (ek-)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%90%CE%BA#Ancient_Greek) was also used in Ancient Greek with the same meaning, generally when the following stem started with a consonant, but this does not seem to have been copied to the same extent in other languages, though it can be seen in words like *ectoplasm*.

Since the meanings are the same and these are just variant spellings, the library you quoted could reasonably use either.

Answer (score 0):

> Are these just two types of spelling for the same proposition?

Yes, that's right!

In Greek unlike in English, a lot of propositions **often** change according to the first letter of the following word. So we have:

- εξ + word that starts with a vowel
- εκ + word that starts with a consonant

More [WikipediaLink](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B5%CE%BA-):

- de- (expresses subtraction, removal)
  ‎εκ- (ek-) + ‎θρόνος (thrónos, “throne”) → ‎εκθρονίζω (ekthronízo, “dethrone”)
- outside, outside the limits of
  ‎εκ- (ek-) + ‎προθεσμία (prothesmía, “deadline”) → ‎εκπρόθεσμος (ekpróthesmos, “overdue”)
- (in verbs: expresses the transformation into what the verb means)
  ‎εκ- (ek-) + ‎ατμός (atmós, “steam”) → ‎εξατμίζω (exatmízo, “evaporate”)
- (for emphasis)
  ‎εκ- (ek-) + ‎τυφλώνω (tyflóno, “I blind”) → ‎εκτυφλωτικός (ektyflotikós, “blinding, exceptional”)
- (as privative)
  ‎εκ- (ek-) + ‎ρυθμός (rythmós, “rhythm”) → ‎έκρυθμος (ékrythmos, “degraded, disorderly”)

Source: Native Greek speaker.

Edit: clarifications.